# please give me a step by step procedure for file sharing using LAN

Tags: ftp

anybody can help to give me the step by step connecting and sharing of files between two ubuntu laptops using SSH or Giver.

Comment: check this link https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SSH/TransferFiles

Answer (score -2):

Do `sudo apt-get install ssh sshfs` on both.

Now you should be able to login to the other by `ssh user@ip-address`, eg. `ssh heinz@192.168.1.17`

If that works you can copy a file to the other side by using `scp file user@ip-address:/path/to/destination`/

For directories use `scp -r dir`.

You can also mount a remote folder using `sshfs`.

```
mkdir otherside
sshfs user@ip-address:/home/heinz/Musik otherside
```

If you look into the folder otherside you will see the files in Musik on the other machine.

Comment: Um... no, I don't think `ssh` installs the OpenSSH server, which is needed for `ssh` to connect to the other systems... and I don't think you actually need to manually install sshfs either, as Ubuntu, Xubuntu, Lubuntu, and Kubuntu's default file managers all can handle connecting with SSH/SFTP to remote servers without needing sshfs on it.  Automount/config at boot, that's trickier, but still, your post is not accurate in getting it set up.

Comment: apt-get install ssh installs openssh-client and openssh-server on debian and ubuntu.

Comment: It is true that the gui filemanagers support ssh file transfer, but if you want to use commandline tools like cp or mv you need sshfs.

Comment: So while there are more possibilities than the ones i mentioned, my post was entirely accurate.

Comment: Um, you don't touch upon automount in this answer, you also don't touch upon that ssh server is ***NOT*** installed automatically so therefore this won't work out of the box in default setups.

Comment: apt-get install ssh does install ssh client and server, i have written that in my comment. For automount to work you should exchange ssh keys. Do ssh-keygen -t rsa on the client side and leave the password empty. Then do ssh-copy-id -i .ssh/id-rsa.pub user@server. After that you can logio via ssh and use sshfs without a password. You can use sshfs in the etc/fstab, but i would not recommend it because itdoes not use the same users on server and client and so is not suited to multiple users. If you want fixed mounts use nfs or maybe cifs/samba. The performance of nfs and samba is much better